# what's the meaning of "rail upon rail of something"

Tags: meaning, phrases

> Rail upon rail of costumes

What's the meaning of the phrase "rail upon rail of something"?

Is this a common phrase?

I guess it means many layers(a lot) of costumes, but I couldn't find it in the dictionary or internet.

Comment: Where did you find this? I don't have much idea either...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context *rail* literally means a rail:

> **A bar or series of bars** fixed on upright supports or attached to a wall or ceiling, serving as part of a barrier or **used to hang things on**

[emphasis added]
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/rail

*X upon X* is a common construction in English, and means many Xs.

So *rail upon rail* means *many rails*.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it means "lots of costumes", as in the amount of costumes is so massive that when you hang them up on racks/**rails**, they take up many.